# Creating a FIFO queue in SWF to control access to critical code sections

Tags: amazon-swf

At the moment we have an Amazon Simple Workflow application that has a few tasks that can occur in parallel at the beginning of the process, followed by one path through a critical region where we can only allow one process to proceed.

We have modeled the critical region as a child workflow and we only allow one process to run in the child workflow at a time (though there is a race condition in our code that hasn't caused us issues yet). This is doing the job, but it has some issues.

We have a method that keeps checking if the child workflow is running and if it isn't it proceeds (race condition mentioned above - the is running check and starting running are not an atomic operation), otherwise throws an exception and retries, this method has an exponential backoff, the problems are: 1. With multiple workflows entering, which workflow will proceed first is non-deterministic, it would be better if this were a FIFO queue. 2. We can end up waiting a long time for the next workflow to start so there is wasted time, would be nice if the workflows proceeded as soon as the last one had finished.

We can address point 2 by reducing the retry interval, but we would still have the non-FIFO problem.

I can imagine modeling this quite easily on a single machine with a queue and locks, but what are our options in SWF?

Answer (score 1):

You can have "critical section" workflow that is always running. Then signal it to "queue" execute requests. Upon receiving signal the "critical section" workflow either starts activity if it is not running or queues the request in the decider. When activity execution completes the "response" signal is sent back to the requester workflow. As "critical section" workflow is always running it has periodically restart itself as new (passing list of outstanding requests as a parameter) the same way all cron workflows are doing.